# Comunicação entre planilhas

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Tenho uma planilha onde existem indicadores que são atualizados diariamente.

Gostaria de alguma forma enviar esta planilha para um cliente e quando eu atualizar alguma informação da planilha, no meu computador, automaticamente fosse atualizada esta informação na planilha enviada (que está com o cliente).

É possível realizar isso?

Comment: [Google Sheets](https://www.google.com/sheets/about/)?

Comment: Google Sheets, Sharepoint, Dropbox, OneDrive...

Comment: Através do Sharepoint, Dropbox ou OneDrive, é possível fazer upload da planilha e continuar com as macros? Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que não sera possível fazer isso sem que você envie novamente para o seu cliente apos cada alteração , por que você envia uma copia do arquivo Excel em questão . então seria impossível que fosse atualizado automaticamente , isso só seria possível se seu cliente em questão estivesse na mesma rede que você e você colocasse esse arquivo na rede . ou então pode usar o editor online do Excel que já vem no seu e-mail microsoft e criar um arquivo compartilhado com seu cliente ai sim funcionaria.

Comment: Boa tarde, obrigado pelas respostas. A questão é que planilha contém macros e quando enviada para o google Sheets por exemplo, ela perde todas essas configurações.

Comment: Só uma observação para a resposta, você pode conectar o Excel VBA com o google sheets por um [API](https://scand.com/products/gspread/), porém não testei o mesmo. Então não sei da confiabilidade do mesmo.